# 2 viewpager instances don't work

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, android-nested-fragment

Im having a case in which a viewpager is not working, here is my setup: I have a main activity that serves as a container for a viwepager fragment:

MainActivity.java:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      android:id="@+id/fragmentContainer"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent" >
</FrameLayout>
```

I add a fragment that only container a viewpager, and each page in the view pager is a fragment, when I add the viewpager fragment to the Main activity above using fragment manager, it works fine and I can swipe the viewpager.

The problem is: If I add another viewpager fragment using fragmentManager.add(), the newly added fragment doesnt work, it swipes wrongly, and the data in the viewpager inner fragments do not load. Although if I use fragmentManager.replace(), things works fine.

So it seems to me only 1 viewpager can exist in the backstack. Anyone encountered such a case and know how to solve it?

As a last resort if I failed to find a solution, I will use replace(), and lose the backstack :(

thank you for reading,

Comment: You can user ```addToBackStack(null)``` on the ```FragmentTransaction``` when using ```replace()``` and you will keep your back stack.

Comment: replace won't help me as I want the old viewpager fragment to stay as is when I click back